# Why does my site show up for keyword that is not even on my site?

Tags: seo, keywords, search-results

I have a problem to disassociate a website form unwanted keyword. I don't want my page to be on the SERP for that specific keyword. I already checked the content, page source, keywords used, meta desc, even the website that link to my web, and I couldn't find that keyword at all. Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to have a keyword on your web page for it to be considered relevant for that keyword. A link to that page containing that keyword will make Google consider it relevant for that search term. It may also contain a synonym for that keyword which may make it relevant as well. In other words, factors external to the content on the page may make that page relevant for that search term.